# ¿Como crear un botón HTML que funcione como un link?

Tags: html, botón, enlace

Me gustaría crear un botón HTML que funcione como si fuera un link clickeable. Cuando presiono el botón, me gustaría que me redirigiera a una pagina. Y me gustaría que fuera lo mas accesible posible.

También quisiera que no hubiera caracteres extra o parámetros en la URL.

¿Como se puede hacer esto?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link

Comment: a mi me sirvió lo primero ;) <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> <button class="btn btn-success">¿Soy un botón o un enlace?</button>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success">¿Soy un botón o un enlace?</a>

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> NOTA: Ya tienes una respuesta con muchas opciones, yo voy a poner una que se parece a lo que ya tienes pero centrándome en la parte de "*Y me gustaría que fuera lo mas accesible posible.*"

Los enlaces y los botones tienen funcionalidades diferentes: los enlaces conectan con otro contenido, mientras que los botones estarán asociados con acciones (que no tienen por qué redireccionar a ningún sitio o conectar con algo).

Teniendo en cuenta la accesibilidad, **no es recomendable cambiar un botón para que funcione como un enlace**. De hecho, esa es la misma [sugerencia que se hace desde W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/link/link.html) (traducción mía):

> Aviso: cuando se esté utilizando HTML, usa el elemento `<a>`. No es recomendado que los autores cambien el propósito de de otros elementos para crear enlaces.

No sólo es semánticamente incoherente, también puede acarrear problemas dependiendo del método que sigas para implementarlo. Por ejemplo, si el usuario tiene JavaScript deshabilitado (algo raro en navegadores, no tan raro en algunos lectores de pantalla), algunos de los métodos descritos en la respuesta de Wiki no funcionarán directamente.

Es por ello que, desde el punto de vista de la accesibilidad, lo mejor para crear un botón que funcione como un enlace, es usar un enlace y estilizarlo para que parezca un botón:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<button class="btn btn-success">¿Soy un botón o un enlace?</button>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success">¿Soy un botón o un enlace?</a>
```

Si a pesar de esa recomendación quieres usar un botón como si fuera un enlace, puedes usar alguno de los métodos descritos arriba... Pero para que sea accesible, debes indicarle al navegador (o lector de pantalla) que ese botón no es realmente un botón sino un enlace y que debe tratarlo como tal. Para ello **debes usar `role="link"`**.

Con `role="link"` estás indicando que el comportamiento de ese elemento será similar al de un enlace (*link* en inglés). Así podrías tener algo como esto:

```css
.enlace {
  display:inline;
  border:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  text-decoration:underline;
  background:none;
  color:#000088;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height:1em;
}

.enlace:hover {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#0000cc;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="enlace" role="link" onclick="window.location='http://es.stackoverflow.com'">¿Soy un botón o un enlace?</button>
<a class="enlace" href="http://es.stackoverflow.com">¿Soy un botón o un enlace?</a>
```

Answer (score 9):

> [Respuesta copiada de acá (en
>   ingles)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2906586/73749)

**HTML**

La forma HTML plana para hacer esto es especificar la URL de destino en un `<formulario>` como una acción de los atributos (`action`).

```
<form action="http://google.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Go to Google" />
</form>
```

De ser necesario, hay que setear en el CSS `display: inline` en el formulario para mantener el flujo del texto que lo rodea. En lugar de usar `<input type="submit">` en el ejemplo anterior, se puede usar `<button type="submit">`. La unica diferencia es que ese elemento permite hijos.

Intuitivamente uno espera poder usar `<button href="http://google.com">` con el elemento `<a>`, pero desafortunadamente, este atributo no existe según la [especificación HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element).

**CSS**

Si se puede usar CSS, simplemente usar un `<a>` con el estilo para hacerlo parecer un botón utilizando otras propiedades de la [apariencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance) (solo IE lo soporta (a Julio del 2015) y todavía es pobre).

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="button">Go to Google</a>



a.button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    appearance: button;

    text-decoration: none;
    color: initial;
}
```

O utilizar una de las tantas librerías CSS como [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons).

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="btn btn-default">Go to Google</a>
```

**JavaScript**

Si JavaScript esta permitido, setear `window.location.href`.

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='http://google.com';" value="Go to Google" />
```

---

> [Respuesta copiada de acá (en
>   ingles)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13719466/73749)

Si lo que se quiere lograr es la apariencia básica del botón en HTML básico, dentro de un tag anchor (`<a>`), entonces se puede utilizar el framework [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) para formatear cualquiera de los siguientes botones/links de HTML común como si fuera un botón. Hay leves diferencias entre las versiones de este framework, tener eso en cuenta.

```
<a class="btn" href="">Link</a>
<button class="btn" type="submit">Button</button>
<input class="btn" type="button" value="Input">
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

[Bootstrap (v2)](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#buttons) ejemplo de visualización:

[image: Sample output of Boostrap buttons]

[Bootstrap (v3)](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons) ejemplo de visualización:

[image]

Ver [Bootstrap (v2)](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#buttons) o[Bootstrap (v3)](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons) en las sección botones para algunos ejemplos.

Comment: deberias poner ejemplos en el snipet, me parecio interesante

Comment: @x-rw la respuesta esta copiada textual segun meta enlaces cruzados. Si tenes ejemplos que agregar, podes hacerlo tranquilamente.

Comment: Sabes si al usar el botón de esa manera el `form` todavia puede ser funcional para las operaciones con el metodo `POST `?

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quiere hacer es un link html con apariencia de un botón eso se puede lograr fácilmente entregándole una clase css al link en cuestión, me explico:

Para dale una apariencia acabada le recomiendo usar las librerías de estilo de Bootstrap, colocando en el head de su página el cdn de Bootstrap (el cdn es un conector que le permite consumir las librerías sin tenerlas físicamente en su proyecto, debe estar conectado a internet para poder usar los estilos, esto es importante!).

Posteriormente, crea un link cualquiera y le agrega una clase, Bootstrap tiene muchas, la clase para los botones es btn, en sus distintas apariencias btn-success, btn-warning, btn-danger entre otras.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ=="
      crossorigin="anonymous">

<a href="https://google.com" class="btn btn-success"> Ir a Google !</a>
```

Espero haberle ayudado. Éxito con su proyecto!